# Understanding the stack in the context of heap objects

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

Take the simple code below. `d` is a pointer on the stack that points to a `demo` object on the heap. The object contains `val`. This appears to be a stack variable in the context of the class, but the object is allocated on the heap . . . . so where exactly is `val`?

```
class demo
{
    int val;

public:
    demo() : val(5) {};
};

demo* d = new demo();
```

Comment: *"This appears to be a stack variable in the context of the class"* Well not eactly, it's a class member variable. It lives where the class object lives and as long as the object lives. In your case, on the heap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `val` is located on the heap, as it is part of an object located on the heap. Each thread has its own stack, but individual objects do not. `val` would be located on the stack only if `d` were declared statically.

Answer (score 1):

No matter the object is stored on the stack or heap, `val` always in the same memory address of demo's object as it's the first member.

§1.8.6

> Unless an object is a bit-field or a base class subobject of zero size, **the address of that object is the address of the first byte it occupies**. Two distinct objects that are neither bit-fields nor base class subobjects of zero size shall have distinct addresses.